# Python nested lists within dict element

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to create the following datastructure (list containing several lists) within a shared dict:

```
{'my123': [['TEST'],['BLA']]}
```

code:

```
records = manager.dict({})

<within some loop>
  dictkey = "my123"
  tempval = "TEST" # as an example, gets new values with every loop
  list = []
  list.append(tempval)

  if dictkey not in records.keys():
    records[dictkey] = [list]
  else:
    records[dictkey][0].append([tempval])
```

The first list within the dict element 'my123' gets populated with "TEST", but when I loop a second time (where tempval is "BLA"), the list doesn't get nested.

Instead I'm getting:

```
{'my123': [['TEST']]}
```

What am I doing wrong in the else statement?

Edit:
Have modified the code, but still doesn't get added:

```
records = manager.dict({})

<within some loop>
  dictkey = "my123"
  tempval = "TEST" # as an example, gets new values with every loop
  list = []
  list.append(tempval)

  if dictkey == "my123":
    print tempval # prints new values with every loop to make sure
    if dictkey not in records.keys():
      records[dictkey] = [list]
    else:
      records[dictkey].append([list])
```

Comment: can you show the code where `tempval` becomes BLA?

Comment: as a side note: `list` is in-built type in python. Your variable name should not override it

Comment: What is the desired value the second time around?

Comment: Also, I will suggest to take a look at [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: I don't see a problem using `list` as a variable. I am overriding built-in names of Python all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `[0]` part from the last line. The value in the dictionary is already a list. It is that list you wish to append the second list (`['BLA']`) to.

Comment: Also, `if` should be `records[dictkey] = list`. Not `[list]`

Comment: Yep, that's true.

Comment: `collections.defaultdict` would be handy here.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `records[dictkey] = [list]` as you did specify at the start.

Comment: @yper Unfortunately, doesn't appear to make a difference

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. You will want to append the list like so:

```
records = manager.dict({})

# within some loop
  dictkey = "my123"
  tempval = "TEST" # as an example, gets new values with every loop
  temp_list = [tempval] # holds a list of value


  if dictkey not in records:
    records[dictkey] = [temp_list]
  else:
    records[dictkey].append(temp_list) # append list of value
```

Comment: Doesn't append either unfortunately. Could it be due to the fact that "records" has class multiprocessing.managers.DictProxy?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. Looks like the append in the else statement doesn't work for class multiprocessing.managers.DictProxy.

I've modified the else statement and now it's working.

```
records = manager.dict({})

< within some loop >
  dictkey = "my123"
  tempval = "TEST" # as an example, gets new values with every loop
  temp_list = [tempval] # holds a list of value

  if dictkey not in records:
    records[dictkey] = [temp_list]
  else:
    records[dictkey] = records.get(dictkey, []) + [temp_list]
```

Thanks everyone for your help!